What CP/M systems with where BOOT ≠ $0000 do or do not allow a BDOS entry at $0005 rather than BOOT+$0005?
While not standard, there were several CP/M systems (such as ones for TRS-80 Model I and Heath H89) where BOOT was not at $0000. As mentioned in that question, the Digital Research manuals explain that, "The principal entry point to the FDOS is at location BOOT+0005H."
I have heard (but not seen substantiated) claims from others that there are systems where BOOT ≠ $0000, but where you can you call the BDOS at (absolute) $0005, rather than (or as well as) BOOT + $0005. On what systems can you do this? And on what systems can't you do this?
Please do not give me assumptions or guesses about which systems do and don't; those assumptions given to me by others are exactly what I'm trying to confirm or disconfirm. List the systems you've tested and briefly state how you confirmed or disconfirmed the $0005 call, and any other interesting information you've found.
(Also, I am aware that the BDOS entry point is not the only thing that DR says or implies is relative to BOOT; feel free to mention other things beyond the BDOS entry point if you feel it's important or interesting.)

The usual reason for BOOT != 0000 is that there's ROM there, in which case it's extremely unlikely the ROM at 0005 happens to have an instruction there which would point to the actual BDOS code in RAM. So I'd expect the answer to be "on most systems you cannot do that, except by chance".

The CP/M contract assures you can call FDOS at BOOT+0005h - It nowhere talks of 0005h (absolute). Why would you expect a behavior that is nowhere in the API contract?

You seem to be assuming that the BDOS entry address is the only thing depending on BOOT - There's actually a lot more "contracted addresses" in the memory area below the TPA (like FCBs, for example). All of those need to be shifted as well.

@tofro I do not personally expect that at all; I don't know why you assume I would expect this, just because I asked a question about it, but I've updated the question to make it clear that I don't expect it, in case that's somehow important to your answer. And same goes for your other assumptions, about what I'm saying, which again, are incorrect.

CP/M uses a number of "contracted" memory locations. You would normally have the warm boot vector at 0000h, aligning with the reset vector of the 8080/Z80, the I/O byte at 0003h, the DSK byte at 0004h and the BDOS vector at 0005h. (Basically the standard base memory from 0 to 100h is intrinsically interwoven with the 8080/Z80 reset vector and the desire to keep the 8080/Z80 RST vectors free for further use). Any deviations from not having BOOT at 0000h must have a really compelling reason, like having ROM or memory-mapped hardware (unlikely for a Z80/8080 system) at this standard address - because it leads to implications like system-specific binaries.
Because the low memory addresses starting from BOOT are also used for parameter passing to the OS (FCBs, for example), software that would assume the BDOS entry location at 0005h according to your premises, should be able to safely assume that all the other contracted addresses in memory below 0100h based on BOOT (BDOS warm start vector, DMA buffers, default FCBs,...) are as advertised in the same low memory locations - the BDOS entry point is by far not the only such contracted low-memory address.
The CP/M documentation bases all its contracted entry points to the OS on BOOT, and nothing else - If you move BOOT to another address than 0 (for the  compelling reason above, knowing that you don't adhere to the "standard"), the same reason that prevents CP/M to use the above addresses for its own purposes will likely apply to any potential changes at absolute 0005h - ROM or hardware. So, it's not impossible, but highly unlikely you will encounter such a system. The large majority of CP/M applications simply expects BOOT to start from zero.

While you provide good reasoning here, you don't actually answer the question by pointing out examples of systems that do or do not allow calling BDOS at $0005 where BOOT ≠ $0000.

@cjs I'm pointing out no systems because there are none. I thought that was obvious.

Ah, so you have a complete list of all the computers that run CP/M with a different BOOT (which is a feat in and of itself), and you've checked all of them, and confirmed what calling $0005 on them actually does? You should list these in your answer. I'm particularly interested in what $0005 does on the TRS-80 Model 1. (It mystifies me why you should go to all the work of confirming this stuff and not putting it in your answer. Unless...surely you're not just assuming that you know the answers to a question that's trying to confirm or disconfirm assumptions others have made.)

The TRS-80 Model 1 ROM (which is not changed in any way by loading CP/M) holds $8e $01 $00 at address 5 (that's right in the target address of a JMP instruction). That translates to ADC A,(HL), LD BC,xx - Not a particular useful program considered the registers are not loaded. No, you cannot invoke CP/M API functions by calling $0005 on a TRS-80 model 1. And there is absolutely no need on getting personal on this question.
